# The "A great app is on its way!" tiles won't install

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

After resetting my Windows 10 start menu layout using [this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/backup-start-menu-layout-windows-10/#backup_restore) method, I can't seem to get "A great app is on its way!" tiles to download. I tried enabling and disabling auto-updates in the Windows store, checking for updates (System and Windows Store), running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, `sfc /scannow`, and [re-registering the Start Menu](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96018-re-register-start-menu-windows-10-a.html). I am running Windows 10 version 1803. None seem to have worked. How do I get Windows to download those software?

Picture: The Download Icons on the tiles are the "A great app is on its way!" [image: Start Menu with tiles]